# httpd not starting due to SSLProtocol: Illegal protocol 'TLSv1.1' error

Tags: apache, ssl, configuration, httpd.conf, mediatemple

I have a subscription plan with MediaTemple, and the server was automatically upgraded / updated. When I woke up this morning I found that the sites on the server and the emailing do not work at all.

I logged in to Plesk (admin panel for MediaTemple DV server), and found an error message: "New configuration files for the Apache web server were not created due to the errors in configuration templates: Syntax error on line 230 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf: SSLProtocol: Illegal protocol 'TLSv1.1' ."

I tried to rebuild the corrupted files, then all the configuration files (rebuild automatically), then restart the server - nothing helped that I could do.

Here are the (not commented lines) from the ssl.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
SSLProtocol +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
</IfModule>
```

Everything is in its default state, as I have never touched apache files (I do not know these).

If I try to rebuild all files, then I get this error message:
Unable to configure the web server: Execution failed. Command: httpdmng Arguments: Array ( [0] => --reconfigure-all ) Details: Execution failed. Command: httpdmng Arguments: Array ( [0] => --reconfigure-server [1] => -no-restart ) Details: [2016-12-08 04:28:35] ERR [util_exec] proc_close() failed ['/usr/local/psa/admin/bin/apache-config' '-t'] with exit code [1] [2016-12-08 04:28:37] ERR [util_exec] proc_close() failed ['/usr/local/psa/admin/bin/apache-config' '-t'] with exit code [1] [2016-12-08 04:28:37] ERR [panel] Apache config (14811893120.14461900) generation failed: Template_Exception: Syntax error on line 230 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf: SSLProtocol: Illegal protocol 'TLSv1.1' file: /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/Template/Writer/Webserver/Abstract.php line: 75 code: 0 Syntax error on line 230 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf: SSLProtocol: Illegal protocol 'TLSv1.1'

The server is a CentOS 6.4 (Final), and the admin is Plesk Onyx - Version 17.0.17 Update #9, last updated on Dec 7, 2016 04:02 PM.

I opened a support ticket with MediaTemple for the problem, but the estimated response time is 20 hours - which is a "bit" too long for websites to be down.

Answer (score 0):

A way to solve this: on line 230 delete the last two entries, then rebuild all the config files.

**Original:** SSLProtocol +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2

**New:** SSLProtocol +TLSv1

Then rebuild all the config files.